# Unable to call a procedure using SFTP param - Python

Tags: python

Do you know please how can I call this procedure

```
#### Transfer Files ####
import stat
def downLoadFile(sftp, remotePath, localPath):
  for fileattr in sftp.listdir_attr(remotePath):
    if stat.S_ISDIR(fileattr.st_mode):
        sftp.get(fileattr.filename, os.path.join(localPath,fileattr.filename))
```

Afer defining local_Path and remote_Path, I called the function as below:

```
downLoadFile(sftp , remote_Path, local_Path)
```

but I got this error message, could you please advise?

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Nessus-Connection.py", line 35, in 
>       downLoadFile(sftp , remote_Path, local_Path)
>   NameError: name 'sftp' is not defined

Comment: what is sftp in your code?

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham, it's a module used to transfer files from a server Linux based on DMZ to a local machine

Comment: Where is it defined? Did you `import sftp`?

Comment: When I imported sftp, I got this message ""ImportError: No module named 'sftp'"" ; I defined this function just after defining variables ; then connect ssh and call this function

Comment: then you need to install it, how can python use it if you  don't import it and more significantly  if you don't have the library installed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [pysftp](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysftp). The docs give examples of how to use it:

```
import pysftp

with pysftp.Connection('hostname', username='me', password='secret') as sftp:
    with sftp.cd('public')              # temporarily chdir to public
        sftp.put('/my/local/filename')  # upload file to public/ on remote

    sftp.get_r('myfiles', '/backup')    # recursively copy myfiles/ to local
```

You cannot use a library without first installing it and then importing it.